# current status of mysql table displayed every x seconds

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Ok. I didn't know how to put this question in Title so here is a quick description.
Let's say I have site with some promotional stuff to give for free (or not:).
When I have something to give I announce this on facebook and twitter etc. and people can come to website and fill quick form, couple quick questions and of course name and address.
But the problem is I have for example 20 pieces of this thing to give for free.
When you submit the form this goes automatically to database table.
I know how to display current status for this offer with some PHP (like: there's only 12 items left.hurry up!), there is also no problem with refreshing this every couple seconds with AJAX. But problem I see in here is when let's say this will become more popular and I will have many offers during short time.
I don't want database to be overloaded with queries from hundreds of people every two seconds.
Is there any way to send just one query every two seconds (somewhere on the sever?) and just somehow update value from this query in any browser currently visiting the website?
I'm not sure if this is clear question but what I'm asking is what would be the best practice for this kind of situation.
Is my concern about overloading the database even reasonable? 
And extra problem... 
In this particular situation - with the limit for amount of people that can participate - is there any threat that I can have strange behavior when two people will send form in exactly the same time when there is only one item left?

I would love to see any directions in this subject. Even general one will do :)

PS: No, english is not my first language :)
Thx

Answer (score 1):

Can't you have one script loading from the database and save it somewhere that isn't the database (a file, preferably) and then it can be extracted from there? This will include a cronjob for that script to be run every 5 second.

Comment: But this introduces new problems because while writing to file this file is not accessible for others.